# JS остановка и продолжение выполнение скрипта

Tags: javascript

Интересует принцип работы alert(), prompt() и т.д. Они как бы останавливают код до момента выполнения определенного действия. Пример:

```
console.log('before'); //отображается в консоли сразу
alert('now');          //окно 
console.log('after');  //отображается только при нажатии "OK" в alert
```

Нужно сделать такую заморозку выполнения всего скрипта только в функции.
Есть ли какой-то способ?

PS await/async не подходит

Comment: _Есть ли какой-то способ?_ - нет. `alert`, `prompt` и `confirm` это нативные функции предоставляемые непосредственно браузером. Поэтому они могут блокировать выполнение всех скриптов.

Comment: _Нужно сделать такую заморозку выполнения всего скрипта только в функции._ - непонятно что имеется ввиду